# Is there a way to reduce the size of the sklearn 20newsgroups dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn, text-classification, auto-sklearn

I am in process of learning the basics of NLP and I am trying to code the kNN classifier.

In the data preparation stage, I am trying to reduce the set size down to a certain dimension but I am confused about how to do that.

Can anyone help me out?

I have written the code below for getting the training dataset

```
trainingData = fetch_20newsgroups(subset="train",categories=allCategories)
```

Comment: "Thanks. Rahul" why is this mentioned here. Is it related to your question, doest it helps while asking or answering question?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is renowned for `Dimension Reduction` which has its own variants, it the broadest sense it is divided into `Supervised` and `Unsupervised`. Any flavor of it using `sklearn` API would be implemented as below:

```
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print('Original Features: ', X.shape[1])
X_unsupervised = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto', init='random', perplexity=3).fit_transform(X)
print('Features after Unsupervised Dimension Reduction: ', X_unsupervised.shape[1])
y = [1, 0, 0, 1]
X_supervised = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2).fit_transform(X, y)
print('Features after Supervised Dimension Reduction: ', X_supervised.shape[1])
```

output:

```
Original Features:  9
Features after Unsupervised Dimension Reduction:  2
Features after Supervised Dimension Reduction:  2
```